# Newbie python script, odometry

Tags: python, robotics, ros

I was doing one online course where on page was special frame to run python script. 
My task in this exercise was to compute the odometry, velocities are given.

This script on page looks: http://snag.gy/NTJGz.jpg

Now I would like to do the same using ROS: 
there is nearly the same exercise but in ROS:

clear code looks: https://github.com/tum-vision/autonavx_ardrone/blob/master/ardrone_python/src/example1_odometry.py

There is information that I should add code from this online_course version to function callback, I try, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#ROS
import rospy
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('ardrone_python')
from ardrone_autonomy.msg import Navdata
import numpy as np

def __init__(self):
    self.position = np.array([[0], [0]])


def rotation_to_world(self, yaw):
        from math import cos, sin
        return np.array([[cos(yaw), -sin(yaw)], [sin(yaw), cos(yaw)]])


def callback(self, t, dt, navdata):
        self.position = self.position + dt * np.dot(self.rotation_to_world(navdata.rotZ), np.array([[navdata.vx], [navdata.vy]]))      
        print("received odometry message: vx=%f vy=%f z=%f yaw=%f"%(navdata.vx,navdata.vy,navdata.altd,navdata.rotZ))
        print(self.position)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('example_node', anonymous=True)

    # subscribe to navdata (receive from quadrotor)
    rospy.Subscriber("/ardrone/navdata", Navdata, callback(self, t, dt, navdata))

    rospy.spin()
```

Please correct me, I am totally newbie to python.

Now i got message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./example1_odometry.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       rospy.Subscriber("/ardrone/navdata", Navdata, callback(self, t, dt, navdata)) NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Is this a class you are writing (I think it is)? If yes, then put all your code in a `def myclass: ` section.

Comment: @hagubear you mean `class MyClass:`, right?

Comment: @jonrsharpe      yes I do! Thanks for pointing that out. sorry trying to switch my brain from one language to the other.

Comment: This is entire code. I don't understand why in this frame on page it works and here in normal code not.

Answer (score 1):

Just ommit the "self" argument, it is not needed. Try the next line:

```
rospy.Subscriber("/ardrone/navdata", Navdata, callback(t, dt, navdata))
```

The error you got is because self is a class member field (similar to the this pointer in java or c++), therefore it makes no sense to address it in your main function.

Answer (score 0):

The direct error you posted:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "./example1_odometry.py", line 28, in rospy.Subscriber("/ardrone/navdata", Navdata, callback(self, t, dt, navdata)) NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

is because in the line:

```
 rospy.Subscriber("/ardrone/navdata", Navdata, callback(self, t, dt, navdata))
```

`self` is undefined. You might mean `rospy` ?

Comment: in above functions, `self` is passed in as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, so I should remove it? I use this in callback. Sorry for my low python skills. :(